# can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8020 aptana studio 3

Tags: html, eclipse-plugin, aptana3

This happens when I hit run in eclipse 
It works perfectly with Kepler and aptana 2.2. (using that in the mean time)

'Launching Firefox - Internal Server' has encountered a problem

Testing WebServer connection failed
Connection refused: connect

I'm using Eclipse Luna
and Aptana Studio 3.6

has anyone encountered this issue and knows how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same setup (Luna + Aptana 3.6) and ran into the same problem. I think it's an Aptana issue and we'll just have to wait until Aptana fix theirs. In the mean time, I just switched to NetBean.